# Magento: Change step order in checkout page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to change the order of the steps in the magento onepage checkout. What I need to do is to move the Review step before the Payment selection.

I've looked on the internet for a solution but everything I found was to change the order in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

I've tried it, but nothing changed.

What I did was creating a file inside app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.phpand inside this file I've changed the line 208 in:

```
   protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review', 'payment');
}
```

what am I missing here?

(I'm using Magento 1.9.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the php code.Keep it as it is.I think let the php do his work. But show the thing you want. Go to `app->design->frontend->[package-name]->default->template->checkout->onepage->progress.phtml` and open and change the order accordingly. Have fun.

Comment: sadly it stops here: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('payment.progress') ?>` I can change it with the review step?

Comment: do you mean the: `app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml` ?

Comment: I didn't get your question ... You want to change the payment step with the review step ?